can't use updated zustand store in crxjs vite extension
I'm updating my store inside background script, and trying to use the updated store inside App.jsx. It is the popup for my extension. But always getting the initial state inside the App.jsx.
store.js

const useStoriesStore = create((set) => ({
  stories: [],
  updateStories: (newStories) => set({ stories: newStories }),
}));

export { useStoriesStore };


background.js
useStoriesStore.setState({
  stories: ["Hello", "world"],
});

console.log(useStoriesStore.getState());
// returns ["Hello", "world"]

App.jsx

const App = () => {
  const stories = useStoriesStore((state) => state.stories);
  console.log(stories); // returns [].
  console.log(useStoriesStore.getState()); // returns []

  return <button>change color</button>;
}; 

export default App;


The background script runs in a separate context, not related to the popup, so you can't use its variables/state directly. In the popup you can use chrome.storage without the need for the background script or use chrome messaging to let the background script do it.

But I think that Zustand provides a global store. So it can be accessed in every context.

Only if it explicitly supports chrome extensions. I don't see it in the documentation. You should probably use some storage backend (not localStorage though), see this.
